# How can I use value-based navigation inside a second view?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationstack

Here is a simplified reconstruction of my issue. I want my value-based navigation to work inside View2. How can I properly navigate from View2 to View3?

Currently, View3 is being pushed onto the Stack, but the navigation remains at View2.

```
struct Animal: Hashable {
    var name: String
    var legs: Int
}
```

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                Text("Root")
                    .font(.title.bold())
                
                NavigationLink {
                    View2()
                } label: {
                    Text("Go to View 2")
                        .padding()
                }
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: Animal.self, destination: { animal in
                View3(animal: animal)
            })
       
        }
    }
}


struct View2: View {
    let cat = Animal(name: "cat", legs: 4)

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("View 2")
                .font(.title.bold())
            
            NavigationLink(value: cat) {
                Text("Go to View 3")
                    .padding()
            }
        }
        
    }
}


struct View3: View {
    let animal: Animal
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("View 3")
                .font(.title.bold())
            
            Text(animal.name)
                .padding()
        }
       
    }
}
```

I believe the issue is with conflicting navigation methods, but I am not sure how to fix this. I am new to using NavigationStack, so I may have a fundamental misunderstanding of how it works.

Comment: Is there a reason as to why you can't unify your navigation methods?

Comment: You should navigate to `View2` with value-based navigation too. Create an enum or whatever kind of value for that.

Comment: You can try this in ContentView
\n
NavigationStack(path: path)

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-save-and-load-navigationstack-paths-using-codable

Comment: @Sweeper Ah yes, enums work perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Could someone add an example for such an enum in an answer?

Comment: @koen This video explains it well: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RPhBPhHw2gA&t=257s

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you are going to use value-based navigation all of your links need to use it. So you can fix it with a temporary `Int.self` type until you make a real model type, e.g.

```
NavigationLink(value: 0) {
    Text("Go to View 2")
      .padding()
                    }
.navigationDestination(for: Int.self, destination: { _ in
     View2()
}
```

FYI you can put `navigationDestination` for different types anywhere you like in the View hierarchy and SwiftUI's reducer will find and merge them. Just don't tell the TCA folks ;-)

Comment: Thanks for answering, yes mix-matching navigation was my issue. I ended up using a simple enum value to get it working.